# c# Xamarin MacOS - AWS S3 - initialize multipart upload - POST request signature

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

Has anyone tried to initilize Multipart upload without SDK (SDK for xamarin.mac doesnt work)? I am trying to initialize multipart upload, but without success. I am using sample code from aws for creating signature / authorization v4. It works with content, so if I try to upload file, everything is ok, but I need to upload file in chunks with multipart upload. 
I am using this sample from aws  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-dotnet 
I dont provide code, because I used sample downloaded from this link. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, missing parameter "uploads" in generating authorization string.